# Command Runs on Command Line But Not in Batch File

Tags: java, windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm sorry if this is a simple question, but I'm befuddled. Please, help!

This command runs correctly when I paste it on the command line

```
java "-Dcloudcard.api.accessToken=s0olREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED" "-Ddownlo
ader.fetchStatuses=READY_FOR_DOWNLOAD,APPROVED" "-Ddownloader.photoDirectories=C
:\UCI_ID\ID_Photos\student\Pictures" -jar cloudcard-photo-downloader.jar
```

However, when I save in into a batch file, it does not run correctly.  It seems to be splitting the command at the `=` sign.  Below is the output I get...

```
C:\UCI_ID\cloudcard-photo-downloader>Run2

C:\UCI_ID\cloudcard-photo-downloader>java "-Dcloudcard.api.accessToken=
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available

... {java usage output removed for brevity} ...

    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for m
ore details.

C:\UCI_ID\cloudcard-photo-downloader>s0olREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED" "-Ddownlo
ader.fetchStatuses=READY_FOR_DOWNLOAD,APPROVED" "-Ddownloader.photoDirectories=C
:\UCI_ID\ID_Photos\student\Pictures" -jar cloudcard-photo-downloader.jar
's0olp4k40nbooqjfvn3mkvbe4ftceocd" "-Ddownloader.fetchStatuses' is not recognize
d as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The command must be all on one long line in you script (batch file).

Comment: You sure that is the correct syntax?  I don't use java but just looking at some examples on  StackOverFlow and the web I would think it should be this for each of your options. `java -Dcloudcard.api.accessToken="s0olREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED"` In theory you should only need the quotes to protect spaces and special characters that the batch file might interpret incorrectly.

Comment: It looks to me as if your doublequotes are not paired, `s0olREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED"`, and that has ruined the entire command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy this **as is** into your `batch-file`:

```
java -Dcloudcard.api.accessToken="s0olREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED" ^
-Ddownloader.fetchStatuses="READY_FOR_DOWNLOAD,APPROVED" ^
-Ddownloader.photoDirectories="C:\UCI_ID\ID_Photos\student\Pictures" ^
-jar cloudcard-photo-downloader.jar
```

It can also be single line, obviously then excluding the carets `^`, but this makes it a little more readable here and in your `batch-file`